# Merkle proof in remix help

Tags: solidity, remix

Hi when i add my merkle proof to my whitelistmint function it fails. Any help would be great also the addresses in the list in my javascript are all correct.

```
Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":3}, value={"types":["bytes32[]"],"values":["0x67fcd2489de3cad4c4be15c58ca60f0df94323e882d5e4483778331ff0e1c766","0xd01f7f1130cd76674aa5de088ae3f127d431228785ba80cfd38ba829672e0988","0xa659baf0c47d053191492d3f464c52edf85b18627eca584c9a7cbf98a3e8dbd2"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

This is my mint function im starting to think this is layed out wrong

```
 function mintWhitelist(bytes32[] calldata merkleProof) public payable
    isValidMerkleProof(merkleProof, WhiteListMerkleRoot)
    isCorrectPayment(WhiteListPrice, 80000000000000000)
{
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(supply + 1 <= totalSupply, "max NFT limit exceeded");
    _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + 1);
}
```

I have also tried adding[] around it which ended up with this error

```
 Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 2
```

If i add "" this is what appears

```
Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="0x67fcd2489de3cad4c4be15c58ca60f0df94323e882d5e4483778331ff0e1c766,0xd01f7f1130cd76674aa5de088ae3f127d431228785ba80cfd38ba829672e0988,0xa659baf0c47d053191492d3f464c52edf85b18627eca584c9a7cbf98a3e8dbd2", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks totally understand now. You have saved me much pain appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Merkle proof argument you're trying to pass is ill-formatted.

The format for a Merkle proof in JavaScript is represented as an array of hexadecimal values as strings. In your case, the correct format for the Merkle proof you need to pass to the function would be as follows:

```js
["0x67fcd2489de3cad4c4be15c58ca60f0df94323e882d5e4483778331ff0e1c766","0xd01f7f1130cd76674aa5de088ae3f127d431228785ba80cfd38ba829672e0988","0xa659baf0c47d053191492d3f464c52edf85b18627eca584c9a7cbf98a3e8dbd2"]
```

While in your code above, you are not passing an array of 3 hexadecimal values but one string that is not readable by the EVM.